# Rails 3.2 how to protect shared resource access across sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, semaphore

I have a shared resource that can only be used by one session at a time, how do I signal to other sessions that the resource is currently in use?

In Java or C I would use a mutex semaphore to coordinate between threads, how can I accomplish that in Rails? Do I define a new environment variable and use it to coordinate between sessions?

A little code snippet along with the answer would be very helpful.

Comment: Depends on what the resource is. Maybe it provides native locking? You need to provide more details / background information.

Comment: For some sessions the user can opt to control a shared resource. if a user were to request access then I want to check and see if the resource is being used in which case put up a dialog denying then access, if is available mark the resources as being in use and let the new user go ahead and use it. When a session check if the resource was used, in which case release it.

Comment: You are using Rails, so why don't you just create a model with a lock attribute?

Comment: I will look into creating a model with lock attribute. If you have some code snippets for the lock attribute, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since your Rails instances can be run in different processes when using Nginx or Apache (no shared memory like in threads), I guess the only solution is using file locks:

```
lock = File.new("/lock/file")
begin
  lock.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
  # do your logic here, or share information in your lock file
ensure
  lock.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
end
```

Comment: This solution assumes you're only locking multiple processes on a single machine. If you have multiple app servers than you're hosed. In this case I would look into a shared resource (hah) such as redis or memcache. Set a flag saying which machine/process is locking some resource and then have all your other "clients" check this flag.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using Redis for locking the resource.

- https://redis.io/topics/distlock
- https://github.com/antirez/redlock-rb

This has the advantage of working across multiple servers and not limiting the lock time to live to the lifetime of the current HTTP request.

Comment: My `acts_as_lockable_by` gem is using redis to lock the resource :) and yes you are correct about the advantages .. that is exactly my promise with using my gem 

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a [Mutex class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html) that might do what you want, though it won't work across processes. I apologize though that I don't know enough to give you an example code snippet. Here's what the documentation says: "Mutex implements a simple semaphore that can be used to coordinate access to shared data from multiple concurrent threads."

Comment: Thanks didn't know about the mutrx class, will check it out.

Comment: `Mutex` isn't part of Rails, it's part of Ruby. That documentation is also somewhat old, [newer docs are here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html). Further, this won't work across processes, so it is mostly useless for the OP's purpose on a web server.

Comment: This won't work with horizontally scalable architecture! as the memory is not shared across multiple servers. you need to use Redis/Memcache to implement such a locking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [acts_as_lockable_by](https://github.com/tareksamni/acts_as_lockable_by) gem.

Imagine the shared resource is a `Patient` ActiveRecord class that can only be accessed by a single user (you can replace this with session_id) as follows:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_lockable_by :id, ttl: 30.seconds
end
```

Then you can do this in your controller:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    if patient.lock(current_user.id) 
      # It will be locked for 30 seconds for the current user
      # You will need to renew the lock by calling /patients/:id/renew_lock
    else
      # Could not lock the patient record which means it is already locked by another user
    end
  end

  def renew_lock
    if patient.renew_lock(current_user.id)
      # lock renewed return 200
    else
      # could not renew the lock, it might be already released
    end
  end

  private

  def patient
    @patient ||= Patient.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is a solution that works with minimum code and across a cluster of RoR machines/servers not just locally on one server (like using file locks) as the gem uses `redis` as locks/semaphores broker. The `lock`, `unlock` and `renew_lock` methods are all atomic and thread-safe ;)

Comment: This wouldn't work if the app has distributed databases

Comment: Why do you think this would not work? It's based on a shared and distributed redis in-memory db. what does it have to do with the distributed databases?

Comment: My bad, I thought it was based on the sql database, not redis.